# Python Daemon getting caught

Tags: python, logging, daemon, python-daemon

I'm writing a script to read a system log, and I'm running into issues when daemonizing it. It is getting hung randomly and I can't for the life of me figure out why. Here's the code:

## Daemon

```
daemon_context = daemon.DaemonContext(files_preserve=[fh.stream])
with daemon_context:
    logger.debug("In Daemon")
    main()
```

## Main

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh = logging.FileHandler("./debug.log")
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.debug("First")

def main():
    while True:
        from schema import parsed, engine, session
        logger.debug("Main Loop")
        logger.debug(args)

        if args.filename is None:
            logger.debug("In If")
            with open("/absolute/path/to/log.log") as f:
                readlines = f.readlines()
                logger.debug(readlines)
            content = [x.split() for x in readlines]
            logger.debug(content)
        else:
            logger.debug("In Else")
            with open(args.filename) as f:
                readlines = f.readlines()
                logger.debug(readlines)
            content = [x.split() for x in readlines]
            logger.debug(content)

        logger.debug("After Ifs")

        conn = engine.connect()
        logger.debug(conn)
        rows = session.query(parsed).count()

        for entry in range(rows, len(content)):
        # Code inside this for loop is unimportant to the problem at hand
```

## Logging

I'm logging everything as I go to figure out where the error is being caught.

When I run it with `python3 test.py --filename access.log` I get:

```
First
In Daemon
Main Loop
Namespace(filename='access.log')
In Else
```

That's the entire log. It just stops.

But if I run `python3 test.py`, without a filename argument, then I get this log:

```
First
In Daemon
Main Loop
Namespace(filename=None)
In If
[]
[]
After Ifs
<sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection object at 0x7fe11c1da5f8>
```

Then it infinitely repeats until I stop the task.

I just can't figure out why it's stopping. If someone could help me out that would be great. I had a different form of this script before I tried using `python-daemon` that was working. So I know the underlying logic should be sound.

Comment: How are exceptions in `open(args.filename)` handled?

Answer (score 0):

This

```
daemon_context = daemon.DaemonContext(files_preserve=[fh.stream])
with daemon_context:
```

is not the same as

```
with daemon.DaemonContext(files_preserve=[fh.stream]) as daemon_context:
```

I'm also not sure if your logger, being globals, will survive the death of the main process during daemonization.  Have you tried initializing it inside `main()`?

Comment: If I understand the context managers correctly, the only difference between the two is the value of the 'daemon_context' variable within the `with` block. But in this case it is not used.